# SQL Server: need to add a primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have about 5000 records in a table in SQL Server 2008

I need to add a primary key. I don't care what it is, maybe an autonumber would be best?

How do I add a primary key to every record ?

I also would like this primary key to be generated automatically when I add new rows!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD id INT IDENTITY
CONSTRAINT id _pk PRIMARY KEY;
```